# I have completely messed up my USB drive. Is it possible to recover it?

Tags: filesystems, usb-drive

Originally it was an empty 4 GB FAT32 USB stick.

Then I installed OpenBSD 6.3 by `dd`ing `install63.fs` into the usb.

Finally I tried to restore it's original state with many commands (such as dd, mkfs, fsck, fdisk) from both Alpine Linux and OpenBSD from two different laptops, and here we are.

```
$ lsblk
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   1   480K  0 part
└─sdb4   8:20   1 359.5M  0 part

$ fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 512 B, 512 bytes, 1 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

In most recent `fdisk` session (after I ran `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1`) it said

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 512 B, 512 bytes, 1 sectors
Geometry: 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 0 cylinders
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8f345c6d
```

Is it possible to recover it and if so, what commands should I enter to do that?

Comment: Do you just want a single empty fat32 partition that covers the entire stick?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: When you tried `mkfs.fat /dev/sdb` what was messages were returned?

Comment: @DougO'Neal `mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)`
`mkfs.fat: Attempting to create a too large filesystem`

Comment: Try using `mkfs.vfat` instead. This should support a 4GB file system.

Comment: @DougO'Neal `mkfs.vfat` reports `mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)`
`mkfs.vfat: Attempting to create a too large filesystem`

Comment: The following link and links from it may help you analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, solve it. [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the stick's current capacity seems to be **1 sectors**. That might be an indication that the stick is worn out and should be replaced. Another alternative could be that the stick's internal controller has failed and is reporting nonsense. Unfortunately that means much the same: the stick is probably unusable.

The current price of a new basic 4 GB USB stick seems to be about EUR 5, so it should not be a great loss.

But if you have the inclination to try and recover it, there is apparently Russian-developed software called [ChipGenius](https://www.usbdev.ru/files/chipgenius/) which might be able to identify the controller chip used on that stick. The next step would then trying to Google for more information on that specific controller chip, and any possible chip-vendor-specific tools for further diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're fine. You've got two partitions on your usb drive. You just need to dd a proper MBR onto /dev/sdb1 that will recognize your fat32 partition on /dev/sdb4 assuming you did a mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb4.

First do you remember what partition scheme your usb drive was using, GPT or old school MBR? You want to make sure you're using the fdisk gpt version if it's gpt. Do this:

```
blkid -s PTTYPE -o value /dev/sdb
```

It'll tell you. If it's just MBR, then great. All you need to do is dd a syslinux mbr onto that drive. Install the syslinux package.

For an MBR partition table, ensure your boot partition is marked as "active" in your partition table (the "boot" flag is set) using fdisk. It should look like this:

```
Device Boot         Start         End   Blocks      Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      104447   51200       83  Linux 
/dev/sdb4          104448   625142447   312519000   83  Linux
```

Then install the syslinux package if you don't already have it installed and dd the mbr provided:

```
# dd bs=440 count=1 conv=notrunc if=/usr/lib/syslinux/bios/mbr.bin of=/dev/sdb
```

If you have GPT, ensure bit 2 of the attributes is set for the /boot partition using gdisk. In other words, the "legacy_boot" flag must be set. Using sgdisk the command is:

```
sgdisk /dev/sdb --attributes=1:set:2
```

This would toggle the attribute legacy BIOS bootable on partition 1 of /dev/sda. To check:

```
# sgdisk /dev/sdb --attributes=1:show

1:2:1 (legacy BIOS bootable)
```

Then install the mbr:

```
# dd bs=440 count=1 conv=notrunc if=/usr/lib/syslinux/bios/gptmbr.bin of=/dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me "losing" the pen all the time when installing OpenBSD.

To be able to repartitioning it/formatting it in other OSes If is as simple as deleting the first sector as in:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1 count=1
```